# How can I create a directive whose scope inherits from parent but isn't shared among instances?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Because with this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: true, // creates child scope shared among all instances of myDirective
        /* blah */
});
```

I am actually getting only one scope for all instances.

I still want to have access to the abundance of parent scope properties without passing every single one into an isolated scope, yet I don't want the instances to share a scope. This seems like a common use case, doesn't angular offer anything like this at all?

Comment: What makes you say that instances share scope? http://plnkr.co/edit/Nose0C2lSZCjx2UlbK6H?p=preview

Comment: Oh wait you are saying they don't? I interpreted this like they do: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes and if they don't I'm getting a bug that behaves like they do. Looking at your plnkr, I like what you did there.. So let the debugging begin..

Follow up question, how can I make them share scope if I want to?

Comment: `scope: true` will create a new scope for each directive instance. Do you have any plnkr to show your use case.